# How To calculate Total Amount Of Items In Basket

Tags: c#

The class below is what I've created for my shopping basket. am I going in the direction to achieve the desired outcome?

```
namespace Basket
{
   public class ShoppingBasket
    {
        private string productName;
        private decimal latestProductValue;
        private int quantity;
        private decimal Total;

        public void AddProduct( string productName, decimal latestProductValue, int quantity)
        {
            string ProductName = productName;
            decimal LatestProductValue = latestProductValue;
            int Quantity = quantity;

        }

        public string ProductName
        {
            get { return productName; }
            set
            {
                if (productName == ProductName)
                    productName = ProductName;
            } 
        }

        public decimal LatestProductValue
        {
            get { return latestProductValue; }
            set
            {
                if (latestProductValue == LatestProductValue)
                    latestProductValue = LatestProductValue;
            }
        }


        public int Quantity
        {
            get { return quantity; }
            set
            {
                if (quantity > 0)
                    quantity = value;
            }   
        }

        public decimal GetTotal
        {
            get { return quantity * latestProductValue; }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: No.  Your "Basket" only holds one product?  Don't you want a collection object in the basket, so you can store repeated calls to add more products?  Create a separate "BasketItem" class that contains, name, quantity, cost, then add those to an Items collection

Comment: ok I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample project here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70244715/BasketTest.rar

This is how you should do it:

**BasketItem Class**

```
public class BasketItem {

  private string itemName = string.Empty;
  private decimal itemPrice = 0;

  public string ItemName {
    get {
      return itemName;
    }
    set {
      itemName = value;
    }
  }

  public decimal ItemPrice {
    get {
      return itemPrice;
    }
    set {
      itemPrice = value;
    }
  }
}
```

**Basket Class**

```
public class Basket {
  private List<BasketItem> lstBasketItems = new List<BasketItem>();

  public void AddItemToBasket(BasketItem addedItem) {
    lstBasketItems.Add(addedItem);
  }

  public decimal CalculateTotal() {
    decimal total = lstBasketItems.Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.ItemPrice));
    return total;
  }
}
```

Use them in your form:

```
BasketItem insItem = new BasketItem();
Basket insBasket = new Basket();

insItem.ItemName = "My Item 1";
insItem.ItemPrice = 10;

insBasket.AddItemToBasket(insItem);

Console.WriteLine(insBasket.CalculateTotal());
```

This is a very simple example, not tested. I tried to show you how you should achieve it. Also not that this example does not handle storing the basket between page calls. You will most likely implement a logic using Session State or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will have a look at implementing this solution and get back to you.

Comment: Just implemented your solution and it has errors.

Comment: Can you give some details?

Comment: I will try your code again and let you know what is happening.

Comment: @L.Russell It works perfectly. you can download the sample project. I included it in my answer.

Comment: it does work now just tried it. thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Glad it was was helpful. Appreciate if you could mark it as answer.